# "Scathing" to describe cutting effect of sugarcane blades on skin

Tags: word-choice

Would that word "scathing" be correct, if used to describe the effect of the blades of sugarcane or millet leaves cutting incisions into the skin (like on exposed hands and feet), as one ran through a dense plantation of these?

Could there be a better word for the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oooh, I'm starting to see your story taking shape!  I have never heard scathing to describe physical injury.  In fact, **scathing** is one of those adjectives that never seems to be far away from its buddies **remarks** and **criticism**.  I'm picturing the **slashing, gashing, slicing** effect of those blades on someone's arms and legs as they run through the plantation, but scathing doesn't feel right at all.

Comment: Thanks man! Yes, I'm working on a new chapter in my novel, and need to be right and creative with my words :-)  So, I guess the following will work: `I ran as fast as I could, breaking through millet stalks, most of them dry and their blades gashing at me.`

Comment: Way to go @nemesisfixx!  Keep at it.  Good reading is hard writing, isn't it?  My brother bought me a thesaurus when I was very young, and it has been my companion for 40 years.  It completely changed my writing and to this day, finding just the right, juicy, perfect word is my passion!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement! Indeed, this one's my first novel project in life, and I hope I can compose it as best as I desire my first cut to be. Currently, I own an old Webster, though I mostly rely on `thesaurus.com` for my exploration of words. But sometimes, I either fail to find the right word, or feel I need the opinion of a more talented mind - English is not my native tongue, but I love its expressive power.

Comment: +1 *Scathing* is psychological, not physical.

Comment: Oooh, I not starting to see a documented answer taking shape!  You've never heard?  Never seems to be?  You're picturing?  Doesn't feel right?  Scathing comes to us from the Old English word for wounding.  That general use is obsolete according to the *OED*, but it still occurs rarely.  Its remaining meanings are 1) characterized by damage by fire or lightning and 2) harsh criticism.

Comment: @deadrat, guilty as charged for a non-rigorous answer. I tutor English to speakers of other languages, and sometimes I forget the demanding requirements of this intellectual space.  I'll save my feel-good answers for ELL.

Comment: You are hereby sentenced to a term of not less than 15 minutes with the *OED* and the Ngram viewer to thereby turn this into a solid answer.  Because you're not wrong.  I don't haunt ELL much, but don't you think the documentation is just as important there?  That's not a rhetorical question;  I'm really asking.  Isn't ELL the place to teach not only English usage but how to go about figuring out English usage?

Comment: And I don't hold this place in that high a regard as an "intellectual space."  By all means contribute "non-rigorous" material even unto banter.  That's what comments are for.  Sometimes I think the commentary is as important as the answers.